# JGit pre-receive hook

Tags: git, jgit

When using JGit do a push to remote which is on the same server.

1) if the remote was configured with `file://` or `/path/to/git/remote`, the pre-receive hook won't be executed.

2) if the remote was configured with `ssh://`, the pre-receive hook will be executed.

If doing the same push using the Git command line, pre-receive hook will always be executed.

I don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JGit doesn't support all hooks; when you push via `ssh:` the remote server's git implementation is performing the git hook support. When you use JGit to push to a local repository it's just updating the local contents of the repository. (I'm not even sure if pushing to a local repository with a native `git` client will execute a `pre-receive` since it's not running `git upload-pack` and therefore not doing a receive.

Comment: pushing over file:// using native git client can trigger the pre-receive hook, while JGit won't

Comment: See [this bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=299315) for how far hooks in JGit are implemented

Comment: As @foolhunger has said, when JGit pushes to local file remotes it seems the remote repositiory's pre-receive hooks aren't triggered. If you want to test hooks, you will have to set up a remote on a VM or another PC. You can add the remote via: `git remote add origin user@machine:/git-repo-dir`

Answer (score 0):

jGit has support for PreReceiveHooks, but you need to implement this hook - it is not read from hook directory.

https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/5.0.1.201806211838-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/PreReceiveHook.html